# How to setup and use Android Emulator (shipped in Android Studio) in a corporate environment (no internet access or admin rights)?

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator

I'm trying to use Emulator on a PC which has no internet connection and I'm not local admin. I've downloaded Android Studio (no install zip) on another PC and extracted contents, but it says "No SDK folder found".

Then I manually downloaded sdk tools zip and tried to update SDK folder with no luck. It says this folder does not include Android SDK.

Then I got my local admin guy to install Studio on the PC. But when I start Studio, I get the same "No SDK folder" error. I guess this is because setup installed SDK folder under local admin AppData folder. I cannot see his folder and couldn't contact him so far.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I got the admin guy to copy SDK folder from his directory under C:\Users\adminguy\AppData to somewhere I can read. Now it works ok.